# What does "paradigmatic" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

Definition from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/paradigmatic),

> ​relating to the way different words or language items can be chosen to play a particular part in a language structure

I don't understand the examples:

- **paradigmatic** analysis
- The **paradigmatic** society which stands behind every historical society is hierarchical, but social classes have a marginal permeability; there are no slaves, no discrimination between men and women.

Answer (score 2):

The word **paradigmatic** is simply made of `paradigm` + `atic`(suffix).

`-atic` suffix, which makes *adjective* out of *noun* and *verb*, **Paradigm** means `a typical example or pattern of something; a model.`  (from google's dictionary).

So the example can be:

> 1. **Pattern based** (paradigmatic) analysis
> 2. The **ideal** (paradigmatic) society ...

Also from [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/paradigmatic):

> The adjective **paradigmatic** is a fancy word for describing something that is an ideal or standard.

Comment: I still don't understand `a typical example or pattern of something; a model.`